# AMD CPU fan bracket keeps breaking

Tags: mount, fan, am2+

I have a strange problem. The CPU fan mounting bracket on my AM2+ mobo keeps breaking. The first time happened about 6 months ago and the CPU fan had not been touched in about 2 years.

Since then I have purchased replacement mounts that only last about 2 weeks. I've tried two fans, both with the same result. A broken fan mount. Neither fan seems to be excessively wobbly or tight. There is not an excessive amount of thermal grease on the CPU.

1. Any ideas on why this keeps happening?
2. Has anyone bought a replacement bracket that lasts longer than a month?
3. Any other clever solutions?

The mount breaks right at the point where the fan bracket hooks on.

EDIT:

The original mount bracket was stock. It came with the motherboard in 2009 (Gigabyte brand). The PC sits on a cement floor, never moves, and nobody used the room the room beside me. So, nobody should be drop kicking it or rattling it unnecessarily.

Until this latest breakage, I ran the PC standing on its bottom so the mobo was vertical (as designed). I thought perhaps the fan was weighing on the bracket so this last run I left the PC on its side on my workbench.

Edit #2:

90-day followup, the blue mounting bracket off Amazon has yet to break. Nothing else has changed in my setup so I'm hoping that this is a sign that the problem was with the quality of the plastic used in the brackets. The black ones seem to have a super-high glass content which lends a nice brittle quality. For those interested in the magic blue bracket see [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008SOEH40)

Comment: These aftermarket equipment or stock equipment?  We need more information.  Something like this just doesn't break.  Are you moving the computer around?  There has to be something that is happening that explains the stress on the material.

Comment: @Ramhound I added some more information. I wonder if the CPU warped a little bit after the first bracket failure and now the fan is exerting more pressure on the bracket?..

Comment: This a custom built PC? I suspect mounting bracket was over tighten originally.  After market was metal or plastic?

Comment: Yes, a custom build. The mounting bracket has always been plastic. There are some traces under the bracket so unfortunately I don't think metal would be a good idea.
Here is one of the broken brackets.
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByD1VDeyef_nVGJ0QXp5bjJsOUE&usp=sharing

Comment: Had this exact same problem with my buddy's computer.  We went through 2 mounting brackets of the yellow variety.  Its a shear failure in the plastic at the point where the cooling fan apparatus clips on.  We were debating either to A) get a bracket made out of metal or B bend the mounting bar for the cooling apparatus so it does not exert so much force on the plastic bracket.  How is your blue bracket holding up now after ~2 years?

Comment: The blue bracket has survived and is still holding strong! This PC is now a media server and is on 24x7. I would recommend the blue bracket.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with my machine and an ASUS motherboard. The OEM bracket broke after several years. I bought a replacement from Microcenter and it broke in about a week. I bought another of the same and it broke in less than a day. So I believe there is a design problem with some of the replacement brands available.

I was surprised to find a LOT of different options available on Amazon, and chose one with much wider tabs where the fan clamps onto the bracket. It is a DGZZI brand:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07T1K7QQT/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07T1K7QQT)[DGZZI AM3 bracket](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07T1K7QQT)

So far it has worked  for a couple of days and I am hoping for the best.